# SuiteCRM, SugarCRM : Many relationships "many-to-many" between same two modules

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

In the account module, I needed to create two relationships "many-to-many" with the same module "Opportunities",
When I access the account module I find that one of the subpanels of oppotunities doesn't contain the arrow icon
to allow me to select the opportunities. Is this normal ?

I am using suiteCRM 7.7.4 (Sugar Version 6.5.24)

Thank you for your help !

Best regards !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you again for your quick reply Amitesh.

I checked the file `modules/Accounts/metadata/subpaneldefs.php`,
and I find that there is no `array('widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton', 'mode' => 'MultiSelect')`
in the declaration of `$layout_defs['Accounts']['subpanel_setup']['opportunities']` array, so I add it manually and it works now.

There is also another alternative, this one consists of deleting the subpanel
and creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not normal , Normally `opportunities` subpanel have button to select data, So solutions for that  is following ,

**1.** If you installation is new re install it  .
**2.** If it is preexisting than check the code of `subpanel-list.php` in your opportunities module , i think button will be hide, or find `panel-top.php` you will get the solution there.